# How to access linq group results

Tags: c#, linq

This might seem silly but I spend enough time and I guess I need more exposure to linq.

I have linq expression which results a group (key=int, list=string)
What I want is simple. I want to assign group list to `List<string>` variable based of a key.

excerpt from sql which results a group

```
var productPerBranch =
    from i in 
    (
        from br in 
        (
            from pp in context.ProductPricings
            join p in productQuery on pp.ProductId equals p.ProductId
            where organizationRestrictedPartnerLocations.Contains(pp.PartnerLocationId)
            select new { pp.ProductId, pp.PartnerLocationId }
        )
        join pl in context.PartnerLocation on br.PartnerLocationId equals pl.PartnerLocationId into k
        from l in k.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { br.ProductId, l.DisplayName }
    )
    group i by i.ProductId into g
    select g;
```

for e.g if I want to assign lists with with Key=0 to this variable 
`List <string> l`  How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query =
(
    from br in 
    (
        from pp in context.ProductPricings
        join p in productQuery on pp.ProductId equals p.ProductId
        where organizationRestrictedPartnerLocations.Contains(pp.PartnerLocationId)
        select new { pp.ProductId, pp.PartnerLocationId }
    )
    join pl in context.PartnerLocation on br.PartnerLocationId equals pl.PartnerLocationId into k
    from l in k.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { br.ProductId, l.DisplayName }
).ToLookup(x => x.ProductId, x => x.DisplayName);

var result = query[0].ToList();
```